# Alternative accessibility software for Ubuntu? (Not Vinux)

Tags: 16.04, themes, colors, contrast

I know it exists a distro like Vinux, but if I have to do a course where Ubuntu is used I see myself limited by my sight issues.
I find accessibility options quite limited, the high contrast does not work for me since it's white high contrast and I need black high contrase like the one in Windows, and it would be nice if applications not related to the operative system would be affected by the accessibility configuration of the OS itself so I don't have to tweak every program I have to use, if it was even possible to tweak it since some don't offer the chance.

Does exist any application to download and install that improves the accessibility of Ubuntu and adds more options and themes such a dark high contrast theme, scalable text, magnifier, etc?

- Scale font
- Change colors of the OS menus, including folder navigation.
- Change colors of non OS software when OS colors are changed
- Include a magnifier
- Change mouse pointer.
- Use of keyboard shortcuts to change accessibility setings or access the options.
  All of this without extensible use of commands, just install a software that embeds in the OS, like a helper and adds it's features, and adds easy tweakings.

Is something like the thing I describe?

Thanks.

Comment: @ElderGeek Can I reformulate my question? I think I'm gonna edit it to ask a similar thing it may be not duplicated

Comment: Of course. There's nothing in the [guidelines ](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) that suggests you shouldn't [edit] a question. In fact anything you can do to make it more clear what you are attempting to achieve is likely to help, no hinder the process. Of course if the called duplicate solves your problem there is little point in doing so. Did you try it?